# How to use stream reduce with different types?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, reduce

I have a stream of values with type `One` and I want to reduce them to a value of type, `Sum`. (it's not integers, just for example).
And, I have a `BiFunction` summator which returns `Sum` (`Sum sum = transformer.apply(sum, one)` with some logic).
And have an initial value of `Sum` (`Sum.INITIAL`).

Tried to do something like:

```
source.stream().reduce(Sum.INITIAL, (Sum sum, One one) -> transformer.apply(sum, one));
```

where `source` - list of `One`s.
And have `"Bad return type in lambda expression: Sum cannot be converted to One"`.

Comment: what type is `transformer` of? are `One` and `Sum` related (if not, you would have to map somewhere)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the combiner function as the third argument.

```
source.stream().reduce(Sum.INITIAL, 
    (Sum sum, One one) -> transformer.apply(sum, one),
    (Sum s1, Sum s2) -> {/*combine, e.g. return s1.add(s2)*/});
```

Comment: Yes, of course! I need to forgot old Sum and get only new one! Thank you so much. Final solution: 
source.stream().reduce(Sum.INITIAL, 
    transformer,
    (Sum s1, Sum s2) -> s2);

Comment: @МаксимМальцев Happy to help.